# paypal notify_url action to php script keeps on repeating itself

Tags: php, paypal, wordpress

I have a small action script that I run when someone buys something with Paypal.

```
Using the notify_url=http://www.mysite.com/my-automatic-script.php
```

I am using the mail() feature on my site to automatically grabs email address and update the user with some info.

Everything runs perfect, but the script just keeps on repeating and repeating itself. (i am getting emailed every 5 mins with this) ..

script here:

```
require('wp-blog-header.php');


$user_email = trim(isset($_POST['payer_email']) ? $_POST['payer_email'] : "");
$us_firstname = trim(isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : "");
$us_lastname = trim(isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : "");

$randomkey = rand(0, 9999);
$user_name = $us_lastname . '_' . $randomkey; 

$user_id = email_exists( $user_email );
if ( !$user_id ) {
    $random_password = wp_generate_password ( 12, false, false );

    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );


    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'first_name' => $us_firstname, 'last_name' => $us_lastname) ) ;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'subscription_status', 'subscribed' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'subscription_level', '3' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'subscription_pack', 'Manual' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'subscription_key', '' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'subscription_expires', date('Ymd', strtotime('+ 365 day')) );




// The message
$headers = "From: no-reply@mysite.com";

$message2 = "Here is my message";
// Send
mail($user_email, 'Welcome to my site', $message2, $headers);


  //end mail



break;  



} else {
    $headers = "From: no-reply@mysite.com";

$message2 = "This user is already registered";
mail('me@me.com', 'Purchase from Registered User', $message2, $headers);
}

break;
```

Thanks in advance! Is break; sufficient for this?

Another UPDATE:

I went the PDT PayPal route:

IT seems like this is working!

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "my-secret-code";
$req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
// If possible, securely post back to paypal using HTTPS
// Your PHP server will need to be SSL enabled
// $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
// read the body data
$res = '';
$headerdone = false;
while (!feof($fp)) {
$line = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp($line, "\r\n") == 0) {
// read the header
$headerdone = true;
}
else if ($headerdone)
{
// header has been read. now read the contents
$res .= $line;
}
}

// parse the data
$lines = explode("\n", $res);
$keyarray = array();
```

Comment: This question is incomprehensible and your example is some sort of pseudo code. Can you post the actual code? Also, start by determining what is causing it to be invoked multiple times: is paypal calling the url multiple times? (is a cron job being invoked somewhere in the process?) Is your example code actually from my-automatic-script.php or is that somewhere else? Could you post a link to the whole file?

Comment: I doubt PayPal is hitting your notification URL every 5 minutes. Like Kato said, provide actual code and if there are cron jobs involved.

Comment: Actually, PayPal well might hit your notification URL repeatedly. If your script doesn't return a proper HTTP/1.1 200 OK response, it will reattempt IPN delivery up to 16 times per each IPN message. Easiest way to fix it (beyond finding out why it's *not* returning a 200 response), is to add a header() field to send this at the start of the script. E.g. `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`

Comment: try adding exit; right after the mail has been sent. I has helped me in few such cases..